# Should we get reputation points for passing review tests?

Tags: feature-request, review, reputation

I'm aware that one can get "punished" for failing several review tests in a row, but where is the reward for passing these tests?  Other than the satisfaction of helping the community of course...

I also know that badges are awarded for reviewing hundreds of posts.  But shouldn't we get a small reward for passing the "review tests"?  A +5 rep or even +2 would be a nice reward for passing these tests.

Should this be added in?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. Instead, delete them or flag them for deletion.

Comment: Please note that [downvotes on Meta may appear to be different](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). Here, downvotes 
may indicate disagreement in addition to any criticism of the post itself. 
Verbose criticisms will be expanded upon in answers and comments. 
Hope that clears things up!

Comment: @RobotHumans Don't really care, it's my question and I want it gone.  Obviously there's a difference on meta where it seems to be mostly high rep point peeps who don't care for things like I suggested.  That'll teach me, being a lowly sub-10k member to make a suggestion here where there's obvious classes at play.  Won't happen again. And yes I've already flagged it as opinion-based, which it is.

Comment: Why is this getting close votes? That's ridiculous.

Comment: I didn't VTC.  Just saying it out loud

Comment: We/they are not DV-ing you in to oblivion.  A DV here is just disagreement on the point of contest, not an attack on your view.  So, if a lot of newbie users helped maintain the site and thought your point had grossly meritorious value, that would be reflected in the question score.  I, personally, was active on meta long before I was a 20k or so user.  
  
The no defacement of your post is related to the fact that actually asking the question does have some merit.

Comment: @Dorian we don't delete posts without very good reason, whether the suggestion is welcomed or not.  Just because a suggestion is not welcomed by the community or moderation team doesn't mean we just delete the post, nor does it mean you should vandalize the post either.

Comment: @ThomasWard Primarily opinion-based is a reason.  Simple. It's even a flag.

Comment: @Dorian If you want the post removed from your account you can use the [contact us](https://meta.askubuntu.com/contact) link at the bottom of every page and request a disassociation. This will remove all traces of you from the post.

Comment: You may need to choose "other" and ask for this post to be disassociated from your account. I thought there was a standard reason for this, but I don't see it anymore. Otherwise I could request it for you.

Answer (score 7):

**No, there are no reputation rewards for passing review tests, nor should there be.**

The ability to review things in the queues is a privilege, it should not be giving you additional capabilities or rewards just for passing the audits.

Normally the audits come up to make sure you're not just robo-clicking through posts, to make sure you're actually reviewing them.  The tests, when failed enough, are temporary lockouts designed to capture such robo-reviewing but also to help identify that "You are not using review proper."  Passing those audits should not give any additional rewards beyond you being allowed to continue reviewing.

If we give reputation for succeeding in reviewing or succeeding in these tests, it's just going to invite people to review *only* to get reputation, which will flood the review queues with failed reviews, crap flags, and additional headaches.  The point of reviewing is to improve the quality of the site, *not* to give you reputation.

Reputation should be gained by posting good questions and answers.  It's not supposed to be gained by 'review' powers, just how you don't get reputation for correct flags or flags which are helpful.

Comment: But would this not entice more people to do reviews?  Seeing a badge for doing hundreds of reviews probably makes many people pass it up.  And no offence, but it's much easier for someone with 30k rep to say that it shouldn't give points...  I'd like to hear more from others with only a few k...

Comment: @Dorian giving rep would only encourage people who don't actually care about the quality of the site to review just so they could get rep. This is not a good thing. We don't want to entice people to review with other rewards. We want people to review because they want to improve the site. If you want rep, go ask good questions and provide good answers. Nobody is forcing you to review, and you are absolutely free not to do so.

Comment: @anon As someone with 5k, I still agree with the other users. Because if you add rewards for passing the audits, then the next thing we know there'll be rewards for every edit 2k+ users make!

Comment: @anon I'm finding him in related questions I make that are deleted